# Where can I find the firebase-admin package which contains the revokeRefreshTokens method?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to use the `revokeRefreshTokens` method of the `Auth` class that is described in the Node.js API document here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#revokeRefreshTokens

It is contained in the **firebase-admin** package which I have installed using the npm command as per the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin#installation :

```
npm install --save firebase-admin
```

On doing this, and going into the installed directory and checking **auth.js** file, I see that the method is missing. Where exactly can I find this `revokeRefreshTokens` method to use in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Initially, I had also tried calling the method in my Cloud Function using:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    //Some additional code here to fetch the userRecord...

    admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(userRecord.uid)
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Successfully revoked token");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error revoking token:", error);
      });
```

which gave an error saying

> TypeError: admin.auth(...).revokeRefreshTokens is not a function.

Let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're installing the latest version (5.7.0). If you did that you will find the following in `node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth.js` (around line 295):

```
    /**
     * Revokes all refresh tokens for the specified user identified by the provided UID.
     * In addition to revoking all refresh tokens for a user, all ID tokens issued before
     * revocation will also be revoked on the Auth backend. Any request with an ID token
     * generated before revocation will be rejected with a token expired error.
     *
     * @param {string} uid The user whose tokens are to be revoked.
     * @return {Promise<void>} A promise that resolves when the operation completes
     *     successfully.
     */
    Auth.prototype.revokeRefreshTokens = function (uid) {
        return this.authRequestHandler.revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
            .then(function (existingUid) {
            // Return nothing on success.
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @Hiranya , it worked! Additionally, I had to also specify the updated version for this package in the **package.json** file under the **functions** directory of my Firebase Cloud Functions installation.